# Inheriting a base class from Modbus static library causes invalid stack pointer on return, but works fine when using base class directly

Tags: visual-c++, static-libraries, modbus

I'm using VC++2017 to write a program to communicate with a PLC using [Modbus](https://www.modbusdriver.com/doc/libmbusmaster/index.html). Ideally, I want to create a class that inherits from the [MbusAsciiMasterProtocol](https://www.modbusdriver.com/doc/libmbusmaster/classMbusAsciiMasterProtocol.html) but it's looking like that will be impossible. My current header file for it is:

```
#pragma once
#include "MbusAsciiMasterProtocol.hpp"

class PlcModbus 
    : public MbusAsciiMasterProtocol {
public:
    /* Also tried without calling MbusAscii constructor and doesn't work*/
    PlcModbus() : MbusAsciiMasterProtocol() {}
    ~PlcModbus() {}

};
```

and the part in the main function that uses it is

```
/* Doesn't work */
int dataArr[18];
PlcModbus plc;
plc.openProtocol("COM3", 19700L, 8, 1, 0);
plc.readMultipleLongInts(1, 1, dataArr, sizeof(dataArr) / sizeof(int)); // Breaks here
plc.closeProtocol();
```

Which throws a null pointer exception when it gets to `plc.readMultipleLongInts` (it successfully calls openProtocol and opens the connection). I did some digging with the debugger and found that the stack pointer after the function is called is 12 spaces away from where it was prior to the function call.

Now, if I don't inherit from `MbusAsciiMasterProtocol` and instead use the class directly, everything works fine.

```
/* Works fine */
int dataArr[18];
MbusAsciiMasterProtocol plc;
plc.openProtocol("COM3", 19700L, 8, 1, 0);
plc.readMultipleLongInts(1, 1, dataArr, sizeof(dataArr) / sizeof(int));
plc.closeProtocol();
```

There is no runtime error and I am able to communicate with the PLC. This makes absolutely no sense to me because up until this point I assumed that inheriting from a base class essentially gave you access to the same public and protected member functions within the base class. But this seems to imply otherwise.

I also tried to use `MbusAsciiMasterProtocol` as an object in `PlcModbus` and write wrappers around the functions I need, but that didn't work either and it gave the error "- The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

```
#pragma once
#include "MbusAsciiMasterProtocol.hpp"

class PlcModbus {
public:
    PlcModbus() : myModbus(MbusAsciiMasterProtocol()) {}
    ~PlcModbus() {}

    int openProtocol(const TCHAR *portName, long baudRate, int dataBits, int stopBits, int parity) {
        return myModbus.openProtocol(portName, baudRate, dataBits, stopBits, parity);
    }
    int readMultipleLongInts(int slaveAddr, int startRef, int *int32Arr, int refCount) {
        return myModbus.readMultipleLongInts(slaveAddr, startRef, int32Arr, refCount);
    }
    void closeProtocol() {
        myModbus.closeProtocol();
    }
public:
    MbusAsciiMasterProtocol &myModbus;
};
```

I feel there must be something going wrong with the calls to the static library based off of that error,  but why it works when I use the base class and not when I inherit from it is beyond me. Any explanation about what's going on would be extremely helpful.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why inheriting from  MbusAsciiMasterProtocol doesn't work for you.

However in your last code example where you write wrappers around functions you have one subtle error:

`MbusAsciiMasterProtocol &myModbus;` creates a reference to  MbusAsciiMasterProtocol object.

In the constructor you are initializing it with `MbusAsciiMasterProtocol()` - a temporary object thus creating a reference to a temporary. This is probably the source of the errors you are getting. Remove the reference and make the object private instead of public.